# Mapping data structure in Java

Tags: java, string, data-structures, mapping, hashmap

I have to devise a function that will take as input a keyword and will output a category id.
Ex:

```
f('dog') returns _ANIMAL
f('chair') returns _FURNITURE
```

I already have the mapping and I could just iterate over the tag array each time, but I have a feeling this is not the best solution.

Is there a special data structure (I'm thinking of ternary search trees) in the Java libraries for this specific task? Should I just use HashMap (or maybe Set (since there are few categories))?

P.S. This mapping is fixed, I do not need to add or remove elements from it once it is built.

Comment: When your mapping is fixed then you can think about using `enum`. There you can define your keys and each can have getter for your mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then HashMap sounds like exactly what you want. You wouldn't want to iterate through an entire array each time, because with many function calls and/or a large array your program would wind up running slowly. With a HashMap, pulling a value (your category) from a key (your keyword) happens more or less immediately, in constant time.

You can build the map like this:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("dog", "animal");
map.put("chair", "furniture");
map.put("cat", "animal");
```

And then `map.get("dog")` returns "animal", `map.get("chair")` returns "furniture".

As others have indicated, enums would work well (and a tiny bit faster) for this too—with the caveat that they're fixed at compile time and thus cannot be changed during execution.

Comment: Exactly, plus making category enumereation would be nice

Comment: map.get("chair") returns "cat" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `enum` like the following:

```
public enum Things{
    _ANIMAL("Dog"), _FURNITURE("Animal"); 
    private String description;
    Things(String description){
        this.description= description;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return description;
    }
};
```

Whenever you want to retrieve the string representation of your enum, just call `toString`

Example:

`Things._ANIMAL.toString()` will output `"Dog"`

Comment: I think you should invert eum values and descrption for your code to match the question: _Dog("Animal"), _Chair("FURNITURE"); There could be more instance for category. Also, I thinks maybe better to use a second enum to represent items.

Comment: @AndreaParodi Thanks for your comment. This `_Dog("Animal")` does not sound right as in the OP's question, _Animal is an enum not a string